# Nested route in redux-router doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

I'm having this route setup with redux-router:

```
<ReduxRouter>
  <Route component={App} name="root" path="/">
    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    <Route component={InboxPage} path="/inbox" />
    <Route component={SearchPage} path="/search">
      <Route component={SearchResultPage} page=":id" />
    </Route>
    <Route component={HelpPage} path="/help" />
    <Route component={TemplateLoader} path="*"/>
  </Route>
</ReduxRouter>
```

The problem is, when I go to location `/search/100`, it doesn't get processed through the routes config. Whatever logging I put into the `SearchResultPage` component, I don't see anything on the console.

Direct predecessor, `SearchPage`, puts its children so it shouldn't be the case.

The path `/search` works correctly and as expected.

I'm new to redux-router so I can't even understand where the problem comes from. Should I maybe explicitly put the location or a part of it into the state? Although, for other components, I don't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Route component={SearchResultPage} page=":id" />
```

should be:

```
<Route component={SearchResultPage} path=":id" />
```

Comment: 2nd pair of eyes as a Service :)